# Like and Dislike Functionality In Laravel 5.4 with our any user login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have news site in this I want like and dislike for post.User will visit my site but there is no login or registrations here if we user finds any liked post he will click on the like button otherwise unlike button.If user like or dislike some post it is should be stored and display in post page even after the user closes the browser and open after some time or some days for that user only.

I have an idea by using cookies we can develop but I don't where to start.I have to develop this functionality in laravel 5.4.please help me on this

Comment: with no login, it's hard to keep track of the users who already voted. if you are using cookies, i can just delete the cookie and vote again.

Comment: Thank you jeo.Are you sure we don't have any other way to do this.

Comment: I think the combination of user agent and IP would work

Comment: One way is you can use database to store the IP address of the vote and limit the vote by IP address.

Comment: @tirtakeniten No, that's not a reliable solution. IP addresses can change (e.g. if your ISP has you on a dynamic connection, or today you connect to another wifi network, or you just use another device (e.g. phone vs laptop). Also multiple devices can share the same public IP address (e.g. all devices in one house connected to the same router will share the same public IP address, due to NAT). User-agents can be spoofed, or altered by proxies. So you'll have a hard time tracking the users accurately by that method. Maybe 20 years ago in a simpler world it would have worked, but not now.

Comment: @hktang No, that's not a reliable solution. IP addresses can change (e.g. if your ISP has you on a dynamic connection, or today you connect to another wifi network, or you just use another device (e.g. phone vs laptop). Also multiple devices can share the same public IP address (e.g. all devices in one house connected to the same router will share the same public IP address, due to NAT). So you'll have a hard time tracking the users accurately by that method. Maybe 20 years ago in a simpler world it would have worked, but not now.

Comment: @ADyson you are right. I would be interested to see a solid solution for voting without authentication. IP+User Agent based is far from perfect but works as a toy tool, I think. It would be nice to know how urbandictionary.com implements that.

Comment: @Harish please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004534/thumbs-system-on-urban-dictionary

Comment: @hktang can you please explain the functionality using IP+User Agent.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple UserAgent+ClinetIP based voting, you can get the UserAgent and IP from the `Request` object like this:

```
$ua = request()->header('User-Agent');
$uip = request()->ip();
```

Then, you can implement record the UserAgent and IP in a `likes` table. Every time you fire the vote action, just check if there's a same row in the table.